# Error:scalac: error while loading Specification, Scala signature Specification has wrong version expected: 5.0 found: 4.1 in Specification.class

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, signature

I have a scala project builed on IntelliJ Idea. I specified scla version 2.11.11 in the pom file. However when running, I see the error shown in the title.

How can I proceed?

Comment: How are you running it? In any case, I would recommend you to use a build tool to build your program instead of using a _(flaky)_ IDE for that.

Comment: I am using Intellij Idea. I think that  IntelliJ IDEA displays the build results in the Review compilation and build the output. Is'nt it ?

Comment: Sorry, but I am not sure what you meant to say with your previous comment, I didn't understand.

Comment: I means that the IntelliJ Idea can build the project and displays the results if it is built successfully

Comment: I did not say that it couldn't, I said that I recommend you to use a real build tool like **sbt**, **maven** or **mill** instead. Also, I asked how are you running the project.

Answer (score 0):

check at:
[Scala signature error for Scala module in IntelliJ Idea Maven project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30080293/scala-signature-error-for-scala-module-in-intellij-idea-maven-project)

groupId:net.alchim31.maven

artifactId:scala-archetype-simple

version:1.6

packaging:maven-archetype